# Pseudo element goes on top and not on the bottom of element

Tags: html, css, element, pseudo-element

I have a :after pseudo element to create a border bottom animation (border coming in from left to right), I used this technique several times however this time the border comes on top and not on the bottom for some reason, which I cant figure out. I tried using float and chaning the display type but it makes no different.

Html:

```
  <div class="search">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 485.213 485.213">

            <path d="M471.882,407.567L360.567,296.243c-16.586,25.795-38.536,47.734-64.331,64.321l111.324,111.324
                c17.772,17.768,46.587,17.768,64.321,0C489.654,454.149,489.654,425.334,471.882,407.567z"/>
            <path d="M363.909,181.955C363.909,81.473,282.44,0,181.956,0C81.474,0,0.001,81.473,0.001,181.955s81.473,181.951,181.955,181.951
                C282.44,363.906,363.909,282.437,363.909,181.955z M181.956,318.416c-75.252,0-136.465-61.208-136.465-136.46
                c0-75.252,61.213-136.465,136.465-136.465c75.25,0,136.468,61.213,136.468,136.465
                C318.424,257.208,257.206,318.416,181.956,318.416z"/>
            <path d="M75.817,181.955h30.322c0-41.803,34.014-75.814,75.816-75.814V75.816C123.438,75.816,75.817,123.437,75.817,181.955z"/>

    </svg>

    <span>Zoeken</span>

  </div>
```

Css:

```
.search {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.search:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: $main-color;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
  float: none;
}

.search:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Visual of the problem]

Here is a visual of the problem. The red line should be on the botttom.

Comment: with this code only it works as expected

Comment: My question is how I can get tat red border on bottom

Comment: Works perfect for me in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLd7bbft/). Might be a floating issue conflicting with another class.

Comment: It works perfect, I think you are using float to `<span>`. Can you please share working example?

Comment: w3debugger had the irght answer, I floated the span element which caused the problem thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases I normally use `position: absolute`

```css
.search {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}
.search svg {
  height: 100%;
}
.search:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: red;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}
.search:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 485.213 485.213">
            <path d="M471.882,407.567L360.567,296.243c-16.586,25.795-38.536,47.734-64.331,64.321l111.324,111.324
                c17.772,17.768,46.587,17.768,64.321,0C489.654,454.149,489.654,425.334,471.882,407.567z"/>
            <path d="M363.909,181.955C363.909,81.473,282.44,0,181.956,0C81.474,0,0.001,81.473,0.001,181.955s81.473,181.951,181.955,181.951
                C282.44,363.906,363.909,282.437,363.909,181.955z M181.956,318.416c-75.252,0-136.465-61.208-136.465-136.46
                c0-75.252,61.213-136.465,136.465-136.465c75.25,0,136.468,61.213,136.468,136.465
                C318.424,257.208,257.206,318.416,181.956,318.416z"/>
            <path d="M75.817,181.955h30.322c0-41.803,34.014-75.814,75.816-75.814V75.816C123.438,75.816,75.817,123.437,75.817,181.955z"/>
    </svg>
    <span>Zoeken</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the float of the span element inside.